# Reading delta values from R&H spectrum analysers

Tags: c++, hardware, visa

I am currently working on a project where I need to read the difference between the minimum
and maximum markers of a Rhode and Schwarz FSC3 device. I am using NIVisa to connect to the
device over an ethernet connection and pass SCPI commands to it.

The operating system I am using is Ubuntu 20.04.

The code I am using is as shown below -

```cpp
// Gloabl Visa ResouceManager reference
VisaResourceManager rm;

/**
 * Custom type that defines a relation between the deviceIP string
 * and a session_t within the Resource Manager
 **/
typedef std::map<std::string, VisaResourceManager::session_t> deviceIpSessionMap_t;
deviceIpSessionMap_t devices;

bool device_exists(const std::string deviceIP)
{
  deviceIpSessionMap_t::iterator iter = devices.find(deviceIP);
  if (iter != devices.end())
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------
// Struct defining the ReadConfiguration which is required
// to get readings from the device
// --------------------------------------------------------
struct ReadConfig
{
  // The center frequency for the reading
  std::string center;

  // The span for the reading
  std::string span;

  // rbw value for reading
  std::string rbw;

  // vbw value for reading
  std::string vbw;

  // IP address of the X-pole device
  std::string ip;
};

/**
* This function retrieves values from the
* spectrum analyser
*/
int getValueFromDevice(ReadConfig &conf)
{
  try
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Set SCPI commands strings
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    std::string DeviceIP = "TCPIP::" + conf.ip;
    std::string CenterFreq = "FREQ:CENT " + conf.center + "KHz";
    std::string Span = "FREQ:SPAN " + conf.span + "KHz";
    std::string Rbw = "BAND " + conf.rbw + "KHz";
    std::string Vbw = "BAND:VID " + conf.vbw + "Hz";
    // logConf(DeviceIP, CenterFreq, Span, Rbw, Vbw);

    // Check if the session already exists and reuse it
    // if available. If not create a new session and add it
    // to the deviceIP to session map
    VisaResourceManager::session_t session;

    if (device_exists(conf.ip))
    {
      session = devices[conf.ip];
    }
    else
    {
      session = rm.connect(DeviceIP);
      devices[conf.ip] = session;
    }

    session->write("*RST;*CLS\n"); // Reset and clear the device

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // ID the device:
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // session->write("*IDN?");
    // std::cout << "status byte = " << session->readSTB() << std::endl;
    // std::cout << "*IDN? = " << session->read() << std::endl;
    // std::cout << "status byte = " << session->readSTB() << std::endl;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Basic Device Settings:
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    session->write(CenterFreq);       // Setting the center frequency
    session->write(Span);             // Setting the span
    session->write(Rbw);              // Setting the RBW
    session->write(Vbw);              // Setting the VBW
    session->write("CALC:DELT1 OFF"); // Removes/resets MARK2 position
    session->write("CALC:DELT2 OFF"); // Removes/resets MARK2 position
    session->write("CALC:MARK1 OFF"); // Removes/resets MARK1 position
    session->write("CALC:MARK2 OFF"); // Removes/resets MARK1 position
    session->write("*OPC?");          //  Using *OPC? waits until all the instrument settings are finished
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Setting marker to min and reading the marker Y
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    session->write("CALC:DELT1:MIN");
    session->write("CALC:MARK1:MAX");
    session->write("*OPC?");
    session->write("CALC:DELT1:Y?\n");
    std::string min = session->read();
    int iMin = abs(std::stoi(min));
    // std::cout << "iMin    :   " << iMin << '\n';

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Disconnect from Device
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // rm.disconnect(session);
    return iMin;
  }
  catch (VisaException ex)
  {
    std::cout << ex.what() << " -- " << VisaResourceManager::statusDescription(ex.getErrorCode()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  catch (...){
    std::cout << "Encountered an unknown error" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

This usually shows me the correct values, but when the analyzer has been on for a while it starts
malfunctioning/reporting absurd values that are too high.

What am I doing wrong ?